# phonegap/cordova app 404 on request "from cache"

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to build an Android phonegap/cordova application using AngularJS.  I am trying to make a POST request but I keep getting a `404 Not Found (from cache)`.

My POST request

```
return $http({
   method: 'POST',
   url: myURL ,
   data: {data: dataObj}
})
.then(function (res) {
   return res.data;
});
```

I have the whitelist plugin installed in my config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="~1.2.1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

And I have a `Content-Security-Policy` set in my index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

But I am still getting the 404 from cache error.  Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I fixed it but uninstalling the plugins and cordova android and re installing.

Comment: I fixed it by remove the whitelist plugin and reinstalling it. I get a message "This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in," but it now works.